# Counting labeled trees

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

here's a question I have for homework:

> How many trees exist for vertices $ 1 \dots n$ in which 1 is a leaf?
>
> Hint: cut the leaf.

Ok, a function that cuts a leaf is obviously one to one and onto, so like the clue says I'll just cut the leaf. I'm trying to count $T_n(d_1,d_2,\dots ,d_n)$ which is the same number as $\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} T_n(d_1,d_2,\dots ,d_j-1,\dots ,d_{n-1})$ (assuming that the leaf I cut before was connected to vertex $j$.

Am I right so far? How do I continue from here on? I thought about translating the sum to a multinomial coefficient but I'm not sure how to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know [Cayley's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%27s_formula)?

After cutting the leaf you remain with a general tree on $2,\dots,n$. Apply the formula to it.

Comment: @yotamoo and don't forget to count the number of ways to place node 1 as a leaf..